# Why cannot I open links in an external browser in a WebView (UWP)?

Tags: c#, webview, hyperlink, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm developing a Web App application that is almost finished, the app has a local WebApp that has some links and I'd like to open them in an external browser (Edge, Chrome, etc.).

My code is split in 3 parts:

**1) Windows Runtime Component:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Windows.Foundation.Metadata;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.System;

namespace CallJSInterface
{
    [AllowForWeb]
    public sealed class CallJSCSharp
    {
        public async void OpenURL(string url)
        {
            await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(url));
        }
    }
}
```

**2) WebView code:**

*XAML:*

```
<WebView x:Name="webView1" Source="ms-appx-web:///Assets/index.html" NavigationStarting="webView1_NavigationStarting" />
```

*C#:*

```
private void webView1_NavigationStarting(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
{
    sender.AddWebAllowedObject("CallJSCSharp", pObject: new CallJSCSharp());
}
```

**3) JavaScript (jQuery):**

```
$("a").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    CallJSCSharp.OpenURL($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

But nothing happens, no error, no message, nothing. Does anyone know what should I change? Thanks for your help.

Additional Information:
[image: Windows Versions]

I'm using the same configuration for both projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues that cause the code not to work.

First - the Windows Runtime Component automatically modifies the naming conventions to match the target platform on which it is executed. Because JavaScript method names by convention start with a lowercase letter, you must call the `OpenURL` method like this:

```
CallJSCSharp.openURL($(this).attr('href'));
```

Now you should be able to set a breakpoint in the Windows Runtime Component and see the method is actually called. But there is another catch - the `OpenURL` method is not called on the UI thread which is required for `Launcher` to work properly. To circumvent this you need to use `Dispatcher`:

```
[AllowForWeb]
public sealed class CallJSCSharp
{
    public async void OpenURL(string url)
    {
        await CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
            async () => { 
                 await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(url)); 
            });
    }
}
```

With this change in place, the code should work as intended.

Finally - thank you for a perfectly written question :-) .

Comment: Glad to hear that :-) , happy coding!

Comment: There&#39;s not much point `await`ing the `RunAsync` call. Also this will crash the app if for some reason the call throws (eg, URI is malformed).