# invokescriptasync HRESULT: 0x80020101' script runs fine in chrome and IE

Tags: webview, uwp

I'm still trying to make the invokescriptasync work. I'm trying the following test on facebook.com and it fails with a HRESULT: 0x80020101' which normally means the script has an error in it, but I tried running the simple javascript in Chrome and IE without any problem.

```
private async void WebView_OnNavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
     await _webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[]
     {
         "document.getElementById('blueBarDOMInspector').innerHTML = '';"
     });
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you invoke any scripts?

Comment: I can invoke the script : "window.external.notify('something');" but it doesn't raise the event ScriptNotify which is another problem :-(

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code and the error is thrown only in case the `blueBarDOMInspector` is not found. I used the following simple HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head></head>
<body>
<p id="blueBarDOMInspector"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

You can confirm that the script works as expected with this HTML. So I suspect the problem is rather on HTML side than on side of UWP.

As for `ScriptNotify` not working - the website must be HTTPS and be added as trusted to `appxmanifest`. Better solution is **web allowed object**. A great example was posted in a question [yesterday on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48971867/why-cannot-i-open-links-in-an-external-browser-in-a-webview-uwp/48972974?noredirect=1#comment84960906_48972974) or [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Universal-Windows-App-bf423aee) as a sample project. Basically you have to create a Windows Runtime Component with a class marked as `[WebAllowed]` and then inject it in the `WebView` using `AddWebAllowedObject` method.

Answer (score 0):

For your invoking JavaScript code issue,I've checked your code, it's simple, the possible issue might be the 'blueBarDOMInspector' object, please make sure that you could get the 'blueBarDOMInspector' object successfully when the `OnNavigationCompleted` is fired.

For your second question:

> I can invoke the script : "window.external.notify('something');" but it doesn't raise the event ScriptNotify which is another problem :-(

Please check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview):

> To enable an external web page to fire the ScriptNotify event when calling window.external.notify, you must include the page's Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) in the ApplicationContentUriRules section of the app manifest.

Comment: I'm on the Facebook website which I checked has the id (only for testing). Does the Edge engine influence the markup of a page viewed through a Webview?

Comment: @MusicAndCode I suggested that you could invoke your javascript code in a button's click event when the page is loaded, instead of doing it in OnNavigationCompleted. If this would work, it meant that the 'blueBarDOMInspector' html element is not existed when the `OnNavigationCompleted` is fired.